# Lilypond v2.19 - How do I overlap noteheads?

Tags: notation, lilypond

I would like to have the notes overlap each other, so that only the stems are turned upward.

Here is the lilybin link http://lilybin.com/fr648f/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix is to use [`\mergeDifferentlyDottedOn`](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/multiple-voices#collision-resolution).

```
\version "2.19.55"
\score{
  {
    \time 2/4
    \relative c'' {
      \mergeDifferentlyDottedOn
      << {e16. f32 e e d16} \\ {e16 f e d c^5 b^3 c^5 e^0} >> 
    }
  }

  \layout{}
  \midi{}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know of these commands. This is great (and should get the check mark), thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** Consult the quicker, cleaner, and *better* fix in the other answer!

---

One fix here is to use LilyPond's `\override NoteColumn.force-hshift =` command as shown below. This moves the notehead your requested distance (`0.5` here). And since we only want to move this single notehead, we'll precede this command with `\once`, or else all subsequent noteheads will also be moved that distance.

```
\version "2.19.55"
\score{
  {
    \time 2/4
    \relative c'' {
      <<
        {
          e16. f32 e e d16
        }
        \\
        { 
          %%% SEE FIX BELOW
          \once \override NoteColumn.force-hshift = 0.5 e16 f e d
        }
      >> 
     }
  }
  \layout { }
}
```

[image]